# how to validate fields from DB before binding the data to the details view

Tags: c#, detailsview

***how to validate fields from DB before binding them to details view***

I have some fields which needs to be validated before going into the details view

For Eg null valued fields should be eleminated ... and need to get some more data for the

fields which are foreign keys in this table (ie have the data in other table )

i thought i can do this in ondatabinding event ...

*protected void dvDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
             }*

in the following function i will pass the req_ID..

data binding in details view ...

```
public DataSet GetExceptionDataDetailedView(string strWorkRequestID)
        {
            DBManager objDBManager = new DBManager();
            StringBuilder strSQL = new StringBuilder();
           StringBuilder strColName = new StringBuilder();            //string strTableField;
            DataSet objDataSet;
            try
            {
                strSQL.Append("SELECT * FROM work_request where work_request_id='");
                strSQL.Append(strWorkRequestID);
                strSQL.Append("'");
                // Open the connection object
                objConnection = objDBManager.OpenDBConnection();

                //Create a command object to execute the Store procedure
                objCommand = new MySqlCommand();
                objCommand.CommandText = strSQL.ToString();
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                objCommand.Connection = objConnection;

                MySqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
                objDataSet = new DataSet();
                objDataSet.Tables.Clear();
                objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet);                  

            }

            catch (MySqlException exSQL)
            {
                throw exSQL;
            }
            catch (Exception exGeneral)
            {
                throw exGeneral;
            }
            finally
            {
                //close the connection object
                objDBManager.CloseDBConnection();
            }

            return objDataSet;
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - can you be more specific?

Comment: Agree with Richard, more details.  How are you binding?  ObjectDataSource?  Or are you using a fully built out DAL/BLL layer?  More code would help us understand and help you.

Comment: iam using mysql DB and binding the data  dvException.DataBind();
here dvException is details view

Answer (score 0):

Why do you wish to remove data wen you are binding, why not remove the data from the dataset before it is returned by GetExceptionDataDetailedView.  That way you don't ave to worry about the details view as it will only bind to the correct data.  also why would you want to lookup foreign keys, the correct way would be to create a join in your sql statement to the foreign table and use the relevent field from the foreign table.